# Patch PRODSECBUG-2198 for Magento Enterprise Cloud

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, patches, aws, magento2-cloud

it has been some time after my last experience with Magento 2 and I've been asked to install a security patch, as in the title.

My problem is due to the fact that I've never used a cloud installation and dunno which steps to follow (and also last time I've been using Magento 2 I do not remember any patch to install).

In the guides it is suggested to upgrade ECE-tools  to version 2002.0.17 
but trying to add them in the composer.json has not worked.

```
{
"name": "magento/project-enterprise-edition",
"description": "eCommerce Platform for Growth (Enterprise Edition)",
"type": "project",
"version": "2.1.7",
"license": [
    "proprietary"
],
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "composer",
        "url": "https://repo.magento.com/"
    },
    {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "...."
    },
   .....
    {
            "type": "git",
            "url": " ...."
    }
],
"require": {
    "magento/product-enterprise-edition": "2.1.7",
    "composer/composer": "@alpha",
    "myproject/module-landingpage": "1.0.*",
     ......
    "myproject/module-advancedinventory-rewrite": "dev-master",
    "magento/ece-tools": "2002.0.17"
},
"require-dev": {....},
```

How can i apply the patch in this kind of environment?

I'm confused and never used cloud version of Magento. It should be actually hosted on Amazon AWS.

Thank you in advace for any hint.

Answer (score 1):

I have applied patch (CE-MAGETWO-93036-2018-07-02-07-06-53.patch) to Magento Cloud, Magento version 2.2.5.

The steps I followed were:

1. Created a folder on root "m2-hotfixes" (see if it already exists)
2. Put the patch file here
3. Now, git add, git commit and push

I found that the changes were applied.

You may give it a try if it works for you as well.

Comment: Did you also modify composer.json file? Jsut added the patch file in directory under root folder and committed it? Thank you

Comment: Yes I only added and push, changed nothing in composer. Try if that work for u

Comment: Was your issue resolved ?

Comment: i have to wait for someone to deploy it, I cannot do it by myself and will give it a try. I will let you know

Comment: Okay, no-worries but on cloud as you push the code it make a auto-deploy. Or else you may also increment the "redeploy" variable if you have Cloud UI access.